# Webpack optimization issue

Tags: javascript, optimization, webpack

After migrating to webpack 4.16.0 i encountered issue.

I have 2 entries defined like that

```
entry: {
  app: ['./src/app.js'],
  index: ['./src/index.js']
},
```

And two html pages

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './index.html',
  filename: './index.html',
  inject: 'head',
  title: 'Content Stream',
  chunks: ['index']
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './app.html',
  filename: './app.html',
  title: 'Content Stream',
  chunks: ['vendor', 'app']
})
```

Using `webpack.optimization` (which work fine)

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Code in bundle on `index` page is not executed until i add `vendor` chunk. But i don't need it there.

I receive `index` chunk contents but looks like harmony modules inializing-running part is moved to `vendor`

So how to deal with this?

Comment: What is present on A? I mean, which type of application?

Comment: React based application with styled components and HMR

Comment: So, you want to split chunks, ok. The logic here is that ALL `React, React-dom, Styled-components` goes to the vendor bundle. being there, if you only add index.js, it wont be able to render the react components becuase it wont find those dependencies, that are inside vendors chunk. Does that makes sense?

Comment: `index` do not use any React components. There are just around 100 lines of vanilla code. Just to run static landing page. I need that vendor chunk only at `app` to cache libraries and 3rd party components

Comment: Well, you said it used... now i'm confused anyways... The point is, there are some dependencies on index that are needed and are being inserted on vendors. Check where the runtime chunks are being placed too